# Using Json field in MySQL, getting inconsistent behavior (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, json

I am trying to determine if a value already exists in a simple Jason array.

In my code, I build the following string:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Groups 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(Members,'7') AND CompanyId = 1 AND Name ="QA"

var numRowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The contents of the json column is as follows: [3, 7]
If 7 is in the array (or not) the value returned is always -1.
Pasting the same string into MySQL Workbench I get the expected results.

Am I using JSON_CONTAINS incorrectly?

BTW: Same behavior with “7”

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteNonQuery` is, as its name implies, not for queries that return data such as `SELECT`. It's for things like `INSERT` or `UPDATE` and it returns the number of rows affected by the update.

I can't remember the exact semantics of "affected rows" in MySQL for non-updating queries, but it's clearer to use a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` and then `ExecuteScalar` to get the count, if the number of rows returned is all you care about.